# Error on SQLite migrations after upgrade Laravel 5.8 to 6.2

Tags: laravel, sqlite, testing

I need some help!

I have an API built in laravel 5.8, i am upgrading the platform to 6.2.
After all changes in configuration files and some scripts php, all my tests witch run the migrations on SQLite is broken.

The following error is displayed:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such collation sequence: utf8_general_ci (SQL: CREATE TABLE events (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, event VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, description CLOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, invitation CLOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, sale CLOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, information CLOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, 
    location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, date_start DATE NOT NULL, time_start TIME NOT NULL, date_end DATE DEFAULT NULL, flyer CLOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, atv BOOLEAN DEFAULT '1', created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, location_map VARCHAR(255)  DEFAULT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci --IFRAME com a localização do evento.
```

My intention is update to 7.x after resolve all issues on 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

In the migrations, was enough to remove the `collation` option from the fields. Example:

Initially this way:

```
$table->string('field', 255)->charset('utf8')->collation('utf8_general_ci')->change();
```

The solution was as follows:

```
$table->string('field', 255)->charset('utf8')->change();
```

Removing this option will not force a `collation` not accepted by SQLite.